# render :partial returning an array when defined in ApplicationController but string when in ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, helper

This method:

```
  def admin_buttons
    render :partial => 'portable/admin/admin_buttons'
  end
```

returns this (not html_safe) when defined in ApplicationControler and made a helper with helper_method:

["my partial's output "]

But it returns the expected string normally when defined in ApplicationHelper.

I don't understand. This is new behavior as far as I know in rails 3.1

Comment: Arbitrary controller methods shouldn't be returning rendered views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, don't call the controller's `render` in helpers.  It just does not work that way

`render` in the controller and `render` in a helper can't be used interchangeably.  This isn't new in Rails 3.1.

When you call `render` in the controller it eventually does call `render` on the view, the result of which is stored as its `response_body`.  The response body is eventually returned in the way Rack expects, as a string array (what you see as your output).

These links may shed some more light on how this works:
- [The controller's definition of render (metal)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb#L14)
- [It's superclass method, where `response_body` is set (abstract_controller)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb#L97)

Comment: I've never experienced this issue for 3 years until 3.1. Calling render in helpers is one of the primary uses of helpers, since it cleans and dries up a lot of :partial calls throughout the app. I've solved this problem by creating a module and including into ApplicationHelper, since calling render in a controller helper doesn't make any sense anyway.

Comment: Yes you're right.  Rendering partials is something you do very often in helpers.  You just have to make sure you're calling the view's `render` method, which does the actual work of rendering the template, versus the controller's `render` method, which renders a response to a dispatched request.

Comment: I figured this would be the case when defined as a helper with helper_method, but apparently not. Tnx for your input.

Comment: Yea, helper_method is still calling the method on the controller.  You could use `helper MyHelperModule` on the controller, in which case the methods of the module would be mixed into the view context instead.